# POSTing duplicate Name values in a hash table

Tags: powershell, post, hashtable, key-value

I've came across an oddity where Fiddler is showing me two `Name-Value` pairs with the same `Name` value, like so:

[image: duplicate Name values]

How would I go about POSTing this data in a hash table? This is what I tried:

```
$BuildFilePOSTData = @{'method'='buildExportDataFile';'method'='Build File in Background'}
```

But I get an error saying `"Duplicate keys 'method' are not allowed in a hash literal"` Is there another way to go about posting this data? Any help appreciated here. Thanks

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the [`IDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface (what [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) expects for the `-Body` parameter) allows implementations with non-unique keys.

Comment: Hmm, that stinks. Do you know of any workarounds?

Comment: @Quanda the workaround is to do whatever translation is being done to the hashtable behind the scenes, and POST the raw data. So if it's being converted to JSON, build your own, if it's being converted to URL key-value pairs, build your own, etc.

Comment: What version of powershell?

Comment: PowerShell Version 4.0

Comment: What are you using to POST? `Invoke-WebRequest`/`Invoke-RestMethod`? What content-type do you need? Find out the content-type and write the data manually.. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706386/does-invoke-webrequest-support-arrays-as-post-form-parameters